# How can i stop a Process if another one ends?

Tags: python-3.x, function, return, python-multiprocessing

i will talk about the general problem before the specific one, so that i can explain it and the reasons why i want to do this in a certain way better.

For my program i need to connect multiple clients to one server. However, the operations that the server has to do are complicated and may vary depending on a number of reasons. If the client disconnects at any time, i need to handle that event appropriately. I originally thought of doing something like this on every `.recv()` line:

```
try:
    conn.recv()
except:
    cleanup()
    return
```

but i don't think it's a good solution because it would have to be on every line where the `.recv()` is needed. For this reason i came up with another solution:

```
#main function
def GeneralHandler(self) -> None:
    self.InitialOperations()
    # key exchage
    self.conn_obj.Send(open("s_public_key.pem", 'r').read())
    self.conn_obj.public_key=EncryptionUtility.TextToKey(self.conn_obj.Recv())
    # and so on

        
#secondary connection function
def HandlePings(self) -> None:
    self.s_conn.settimeout(5)
    while True:
        if self.pings_counter == 3:
            self.OnDisconnectCleanup()
            return
        self.s_conn_obj.Send("ping")
        if not self.s_conn_obj.Recv() == "pong":
            self.pings_counter = self.pings_counter + 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

in the code above, a client connects two times, creating two "channels" that i can communicate through. One of them handles the general communication, the other one (`HandlePings()`) will constantly ping the client to see if it's still connected. If 3 pings were missed, `HandlePings()` will perform the `OnDisconnectCleanup()` function to handle the disconnection and then return.

## And here is the question:

How can i make the `GeneralHandler()` function stop whenever the `HandlePings()` detects that a client is no longer online?

Please note: the two functions are run as processes using the `multiprocessing` library.

As i stated before, i tried to use a try statement. It works, but it takes up 4 lines of code for every `.recv()` statement, makes the code hard to read, and i feel that a better solution must exist.

I tried to make the object destroy itself, but after a bit of research i found that this was not a good way.

I tried to have the `HandlePings()` function update a boolean variable, but i cannot check it from `GeneralHandler()` using a separate while loop, because obviously if i write `return` in the loop it exits the loop but not the function.